# Dropped FaceTime calls

Tags: facetime

Every night between 9:50 and 10 pm, FaceTime drops my call. I can get it back within minutes, but even texting is slowed during that time. It doesn't matter who I'm talking to or which device I'm on, MacBook Pro, iPad, or iPhone. I have tried turning off everything except whatever device I've using, to no avail. My ISP says something is uploading every night at that time, but with devices off, what can it be? Do I have some malware? If you have some wisdom, I would appreciate it! (In layman's terms, please?)

Comment: *My ISP says something is uploading every night at that time*. This is going to take some work on your part since nobody has visibility into your network.  Start by turning off every single device that's connected to your network except the one FaceTime device.  If it continues, you've got at least one culprit to focus on.  If it doesn't, start turning them on one-by-one. The other option is to get a router or a network sniffer that can monitor traffic by device (usually a higher end router like pfSense will have this capability).

Comment: In layman’s terms - who set up your network? They would need to look at the router to diagnose network drops. Especially since it happens on more than one app or device.